# How to use extract tables from websites using python

Tags: python

I'm really interested in learning how to scrape data, specifically tables from websites using any libraries.
Right now I'm using this to get the table from this website https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

```
import requests
import pandas as pd    

url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
html = requests.get(url).content

df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]

print(df)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

However, every time I get this '...' in the content, which skips 3 columns.
How can I fix this?

1. How can I obtain the numeric data, for example just getting the number of deaths and store it in a list
2. How can I replace the 'NaN' to '-'?

Comment: `...` is used only when you print long rows which is longer then screen but all data are in `df` so you can use it. Pandas has option to change it.

Comment: BTW: you don't need requests - `read_html('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')`

Comment: you should go to pandas page and read tutorials , documentation or use Google to find some tutorial. You get answers faster when you use Google.

Comment: `df['Total Deaths'][ df['Total Deaths'].notna() ].to_list()`

Comment: `df[ df['Total Deaths'].isna() ] = '-'`